# Use full column height within a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a possible way to adopt a row to have full column height in bootstrap? I would like to use the whole white space inside the row and add it within the col-xs-3 column heights.

Here is an example:
[image]

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Please post the code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap's grid system allows for `.row`s to be children of `.container` (or `.container-fluid`) and for `.col-*-*`s to be children of `.row`s. Furthermore, `.col-*-*`s can parent other `.row`s.

By default, a `.row`s height is determined by its columns. If you want it to have a particular height, you can apply it using custom CSS (`min-height` + `display: flex` - which makes all cols on a row wrap stretch to same height):

```
.row.my-row {
  min-height: 100vh; /* viewport (screen) height */
  display: flex; /* makes its cols expand to full height */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
```

If, for example, you want to deduct top bar's height from row's minimal height, you could use `min-height: calc(100vh - 60px)` - where `60px` is menu's height.